# Cohomology of a smoothly embedded space curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space, characteristic-classes

Let $\mathbb{P}^3 = P(\mathbb{C}^4)$ and $\gamma:C\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^3$ be a smoothly embedded algebraic space curve. Then its total Chern class is $c(C) = c(TC) = 1+a\in H^*(C)$, where $a^2=0$. Since $C$ is compact and orientable we have Poincare duality and hence a well defined 'shriek - map' $$\gamma^!: H^*(C)\overset{PD_C}{\longrightarrow} H_{2-*}(M) \overset{\gamma_*}{\longrightarrow} H_{2-*}(\mathbb{P}^3)\overset{PD_{\mathbb{P}^3}^{-1}}{\longrightarrow}H^{*+4}(\mathbb{P}^3).$$

Let $g$ be the genus of $C$ and let $\chi(C):=2-2g$ and $d$ be the degree of $C$. Then $$\gamma^!(1) = d\cdot c_1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(1))^2\quad\text{and }\quad \gamma^!(a) = \chi \cdot c_1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(1))^3.$$

Does anyone know why these two relations hold and point me to some literature? My knowledge in algebraic geometry is very limited since I am more familiar with manifolds, homology/cohomolgy of topological spaces so Chern classes for me are always defined in that context. I know that there are Chern classes in algebraic geometry (i.e. for Chow rings) and that these notions are related, but my understanding is very superficial.

Still it would help me a lot if I could understand the relations above. Thanks!

Comment: The answer is pretty exhaustive, but let me just mention that there is a functorial map $A^*(X) \to H^{2*}(X)$ when said groups are defined, and it basically does what you expect. So your knowledge of topological Chern classes can be ported with relative ease to AG.

Comment: It is, and I don't expect anyone to give me all the details but maybe sketch the ideas behind it and tell me what keywords to look for. At my institute, I am literally the only one working with cohomology/homology, characteristic classes and so on so there is nobody to ask.

Comment: Take a look at Eisenbud-Harris' *3264 & All That*. It's an introduction to methods of working with the Chow ring based on solving specific enumerative problems that should give you a pretty good idea of how these things fit together. It was deliberately written to be as orthogonal as possible in presentation to Fulton's *Intersection Theory*, which is the unique rigorous exposition of the foundations of this subject and is a useful supplement.

Comment: I actually have it here but I found myself getting distracted by details about schemes. Still, I know most of what I know about Chow rings from this book. I work in the field of global singularity theory, mostly Thom polynomials. The language used there is mostly algebraic topology, but there are applications in enumerative geometry, that unavoidably lead to algebraic geometry...

Comment: I see; I suppose there's nothing in particular to clear up then? It's just a global problem with the language?

Comment: I'd call myself a beginner still so there are many things in particular I haven't quite understood yet. Eric below answered my specific question very detailed, but still I have to work my way through his the answer step by step. The key point, as I see it, is the relation of Poincaré duality of fundamental classes of oriented submanifolds and their intersection.

Comment: OK; one thing I might recommend if Eisenbud and Harris' use of scheme-theoretic language is confusing you is taking a look at their older book *The Geometry of Schemes*. I believe in the introduction of *3264* they say something like "an evening spent with *TGoS* is probably enough background in schemes for getting started with this book." It's a fairly short and informal book that is unconcerned with systematic exposition; instead, the focus is on elucidating how the language of schemes gives us access to more refined geometric information via pictures and examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can understand these facts using just a bare minimum of algebraic geometry.
All you need to know about $c_1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(1))$ in this context is that it is the standard generator of $H^2(\mathbb{P}^3)$ (corresponding to the fundamental class of $\mathbb{P}^1=S^2$ when you restrict to $\mathbb{P}^1\subset\mathbb{P}^3$).  This can also be described as the Poincaré dual of the fundamental class of $\mathbb{P}^2\subset\mathbb{P}^3$, or of any hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^3$ (since the inclusion maps of different hyperplanes $\mathbb{P}^2\to\mathbb{P}^3$ are all homotopic).  How you prove this depends on how you define Chern classes, but for some definitions it is essentially by definition: for instance the first Chern class of the tautological line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^\infty$ can be defined to be negative the standard generator of $H^2(\mathbb{P}^\infty)$, and then for other line bundles it can be defined by pulling back under the classifying map to $\mathbb{P}^\infty$.  The bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(1)$ is just the dual of the tautological bundle on $\mathbb{P}^3$, so its first Chern class is the negative of the first Chern class of the tautological bundle, which is just the pullback of the tautological bundle under the inclusion $\mathbb{P}^3\to\mathbb{P}^\infty$.

Let me now say a bit about Poincaré duality on $\mathbb{P}^3$.  If you have two smooth oriented submanifolds $A$ and $B$ of an oriented manifold which intersect transversely, then the Poincaré dual of the fundamental class of the intersection $A\cap B$ is just the cup product of the Poincaré duals of the fundamental classes of $A$ and $B$.  This plays very nicely with smooth subvarieties of $\mathbb{P}^3$ via Bézout's theorem.  In particular, if $H\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ is a hyperplane, Bézout's theorem says that for any smooth curve $C\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ of degree $d$ which intersects $H$ transversely, $C$ and $H$ intersect at $d$ points.  So, writing $t$ for the Poincaré dual of the fundamental class of $H$ (which, as mentioned above, is $c_1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(1))$) and $c$ for the Poincaré dual of the fundamental class of $C$, $tc=dt^3$.

Now to compute $\gamma^!(1)$, we first take the Poincaré dual of $1\in H^0(C)$, which is just the fundamental class $[C]\in H_2(C)$.  Then we push this forward to get the class $[C]\in H_2(\mathbb{P}^3)$, and take its Poincaré dual $c\in H^4(\mathbb{P}^3)$.  Since $tc=dt^3$, this class $c=\gamma^!(1)$ must be $dt^2$.

To compute $\gamma^!(a)$, we first take the Poincaré dual of $a=c_1(TC)\in H^2(C)$.  The top Chern class of a vector bundle is the same as its Euler class, and the Euler class of the tangent bundle of an oriented manifold is dual to the Euler characteristic of the manifold (that's why it's called the Euler class).  So the Poincaré dual of $a$ is $\chi\in H_0(C)$ (when you identify $H_0(C)$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ in the canonical way).  Pushing this forward to $\mathbb{P}^3$ we get $\chi\in H_0(\mathbb{P}^3)$, whose Poincaré dual is $\chi t^3$.

Comment: This was indeed very helpful, thanks! I have a decent understanding of Chern classes in the context of topology, i.e. Milnor/Stasheff is my "bible" in that regard. I know that the $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$ notations means Serre's twisted sheaves and that it's the same as (tensor products) of the tautological line bundle and/or its duals for $X=\mathbb{P}^n$. But still I would call myself a beginner in that field (as you see from my question), especially when it comes to applications and the relation to AG.
Your explanations are very helpful for me!